# how to edit/change name in output in javafx

Tags: javafx

here is my code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;


public class Main extends Application
{
    private BorderPane root;
    TreeView<String> tree;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        root = new BorderPane();        
        root.setLeft(getLeftHBox());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 500);        
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFx");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    
    }

    private HBox getLeftHBox()
    {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        Text text= new Text("Fall tree");
        text.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD,16));
        VBox vbox =new VBox(10);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TreeItem<String> Library,module,unite,translateA ,translateB,rotate;

        //Root
        Library = new TreeItem<>();
        Library.setExpanded(true);
        //module-Child of Root
        module = makeBranch("module",Library);
        makeBranch("Parameter X",module);
        makeBranch("Parameter y",module);
        //Unite-Child of module
        unite = makeBranch("unite",module);
        makeBranch("Parameter uX",unite);
        makeBranch("Parameter uy",unite);
        //TranslateA-Child of Unite
        translateA = makeBranch("translateA",unite);
        makeBranch("Parameter taX",translateA);
        makeBranch("Parameter tay",translateA);
        //TranslateB-Sibling of TranslateA
        translateB = makeBranch("translateB",unite);
        makeBranch("Parameter tbX",translateB);
        makeBranch("Parameter tby",translateB);
        //Rotate-Child of TranslateB
        rotate = makeBranch("rotate",translateB);
        makeBranch("Parameter RX",rotate);
        makeBranch("Parameter RY",rotate);

        tree= new TreeView<>(Library);
        tree.setShowRoot(false);

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(text,tree);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        return hbox;
    }

    private TreeItem<String> makeBranch(String title, TreeItem<String> parent) {
        TreeItem<String>item = new TreeItem<>(title);
        item.setExpanded(true);
        parent.getChildren().add(item);
        return item;

        }   


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

in the output i got the fall tree/drop down menu. my question is how to edit the  names in output. how can i give new titles/names to branches in output and that appear in my code.

Example: when you execute program, i have a branch name "module" on top of output. i want to change that name and write "Rotate_Module" in output.

(i can simply change the code to do that but i want to change it in output and that should automatically appear in my code)

Note# i want to change every name. thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "change it in output"?

Comment: @James_D, it means i want to edit the output and rename the branches, (like if i double click on branch i can change its name)

Comment: You mean you want the user to be able to edit them? So what does "i want to change it in output and *that should automatically appear in my code*" mean?

Comment: @James_D, yes if user change the name by double clicking on output and that name should remains when they execute code next time.                                     Example: like user change name of module into Rotate_Module, next time when user execute that code name should be Rotate_Module on output.

Comment: If you want to save changes between program execution, you will need to use a file or database to store and load the data.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson, yes i know that is complex but right now i just want to double click on output and change its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the tree editable, which is what I think you mean in this question, you need to specify that you want the tree to use cells which incorporate a text field. You can do this with:

```
tree.setEditable(true);
tree.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView());
```

If the user edits the tree and makes changes, then those changes will be stored in the `TreeItem`'s `valueProperty()`; i.e. you can retrieve the values with `module.getValue()`, etc.

So to make the user's changes persistent, you will need to retrieve all those values and save them to a file (or database, or some other kind of persistent storage) when the application closes. To use those values, when you start the application, read the values from the file (or database, etc) and use those values when you create the tree items.

Comment: The details for how to make the values persistent are too much for an answer on this forum. You should try to implement that yourself, and post a specific question if you have problems doing so.

Comment: thank you so much. Can you provide any link for learning how to retrieve values and saving them. that would be much help. thanks

Comment: @Muddassir There is nothing specific, because there are so many ways to do this (save to database, save to file, if file, what kind of format you want to save in, etc etc etc). So you need to decide a strategy first, then search for help on that particular mechanism ("how do I read and write to a properties file in Java", or whatever...)